What exactly is the type of class
type Equal<A, B> = (<T>() => T extends A ? 1 : 0) extends <T>() => T extends B
  ? 1
  : 0
  ? true
  : false

class Point {
  x: number
  y: number

  constructor(x: number, y: number) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  }
}
interface PointConstructor {
  new (x: number, y: number): Point
}

type bo = Equal<typeof Point, PointConstructor> // type bo = false
type bo1 = typeof Point extends PointConstructor ? true : false // type bo1 = true
type bo1 = PointConstructor  extends typeof Point ? true : false // type bo2 = true

Why are the Point constructor types and PointConstructor interfaces different In the Equal type tool?

Do you know what the Equal type tool is or how it works? It's strange and depends on implementation details of TypeScript that could be surprising. Nobody can quite agree on what a type-level equality operator means (see ms/TS#48100). All we can say here is that typeof Point and PointConstructor are not "identical" in the compiler. If all you care about is mutual assignability (e.g., your two bo1 types) then you should use that instead of the mysterious Equal. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?
